# Как сделать товары с разными характеристиками и ценой?

Tags: база-данных, веб-программирование, laravel, архитектура, eloquent

Подскажите, как можно сделать товары, которые будут в разных вариантах? Соответственно у каждого варианта товара будут свои характеристики и цена. СУБД использую mysql.

Есть вариант сделать таблицу товаров. Товар будет иметь несколько разновидностей, к которым будут привязаны свойства(в отдельной таблице) и цена. Но здесь стоит проблема выборки, а также некоторая неоднозначность. Например, в этом случае в корзину будет добавляться не товар, а его разновидность, что кажется как то не очень круто. Вообщем подскажите плиз, как это лучше реализовать.

На всякий случай пример свойств товара =)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Представляется таким образом:

products

- id
- title
- price

product_options

- id
- product_id
- product_type_id
- product_type_option_id

product_types

- id
- title

product_type_options

- id
- product_type_id
- title
- additional_price

cart

- product_id
- product_option_id